# Populating a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi I'm building a dictionary where each key is a customer name and each value is a list of tuples which are purchased by each customer, like so: (product, quantity).  For example:

```
{'customer1': (('milk', 3), ('bread', 5), ('eggs', 2)),
 'customer2': (('cheese', 2), ('cereal', 7))}
```

I am populating the dictionary based on the results of a SQL query.  Being a Java programmer new to Python, can someone suggest the "pythonic" way to do this?  Each row from the query contains customer name, product, quantity.

Comment: I'd say it depends strongly on what you are going to do with the data afterwards. Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: Have you attempted anything so far?  What makes you think your approach is "unpythonic"?

Comment: I'll be populating an html table in a Django webpage.  The area of my uncertainty is how to do a .append() on a dictionary entry value.

Comment: you can just address the new element dict["key"] = value (see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, I'd use lists rather than tuples as dictionary entries. The principal difference is that lists are mutable, whereas tuples are not.

I think [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a good for for this problem:

```
from collections import defaultdict

customers = defaultdict(list)
```

You can add entries like so (of course in your case you'd do this in a loop):

```
customers['customer1'].append(('milk', 3))
customers['customer1'].append(('bread', 5))
customers['customer2'].append(('cereal', 7))
```

The result is:

```
>>> print dict(customers)
{'customer1': [('milk', 3), ('bread', 5)], 'customer2': [('cereal', 7)]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your inner structure should be a list, not a tuple, since the structure is homogenous.

```
{'customer1': [('milk', 3), ('bread', 5), ('eggs', 2)],
 'customer2': [('cheese', 2), ('cereal', 7)]}
```

This will also allow you to use `.append()` on them, and you can use `collections.defaultdict` to start off each value with an empty list for further simplification.

Answer (score 1):

Im hoping that you have a list of lists from your database, so e.g.

```
rows = [('customer1', ('milk', 2)), ('customer12', ('bread', 4))] # etc etc
```

Then you can simply do.

```
for row in rows:
    cust_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

Comment: OBVIOUSLY I cannot see what your database layer returned

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I'd do

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = (
    ('customer1', 'milk', 3),
    ('customer1', 'bread', 5),
    ('customer1', 'eggs', 2),
    ('customer2', 'cheese', 2),
    ('customer2', 'cereal', 7),
    )

result = defaultdict(list)
for name, what, amount in data:
    result[name].append((what, amount))

from pprint import pprint
result = dict(result)
pprint(result)
```

Which prints

```
{'customer1': [('milk', 3), ('bread', 5), ('eggs', 2)],
 'customer2': [('cheese', 2), ('cereal', 7)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) and instantiate it as a list, and append the fields you want to it in your loop, for eg. if you wanted the entire row except the first element you could do `your_defaultdict_instance[row[0]].append(row[1:])` which will neatly build everything up.